# Passing predefined Object to Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, http-post, swift4, alamofire

I'm trying to pass a Object in Alamofire but no success. Following is my object

```
class MyRequestObject : NSObject, Codable {

var myData : MyDataType?
var simpleString : String?

}
```

MyRequestObject is a nested object with 3-4 nested objects and I'm filling all the objects at some point before finally getting to this VC where I'll make the API Call. Now When I get to the final VC, i have the Object filled with data and ready to send with the Request but Alamofire won't accept the object in Parameters. This is what i'm trying to do

```
    let parameters = [
        "RequestID" : self.rID,
        "RequestTime" : "self.rTime",
        "RequestObject" : myRequestObject
    ]
```

getting this error in log `Invalid type in JSON write FOO.MyRequestObject`

while if I recreate the complete object in `parameters` like this (just Shorter object for reference)

```
        let parameters = [
        "RequestID" : self.rID,
        "RequestTime" : self.rTime,
        "RequestObject" : [
            "key" : self.SomeValue,
            "key" : self.SomeValue,
            "key" : self.SomeValue,
            "seconNestedObj"[
                "key" : self.SomeValue,
                "thirdNetedObj" : [
                    "key" : self.SomeValue,
                    "key" : self.SomeValue
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

it works. BUT I don't want to recreate everything here. Is there any way to do it or I'll have to do the recreation thing here.

I've done something similar in Android and it worked and I was expecting something similar here in swift.

Can someone please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Alamofire 5, you can use any `Encodable` type as parameters, so I suggest you make your root parameters object an actual `Encodable` type and build your requests that way.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet of what you are trying to say please.. i don't understand.

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#request-parameters-and-parameter-encoders